# Impose voxel grid on 3D point cloud

Tags: matlab, points, kdtree, voxel, octree

I am working with structured 2.5D and unstructured 3D data, which generally is available in (X,Y,Z) coordinates, i.e. point clouds. Now I want to impose a regular voxel grid onto the data. This is not meant for visualization purposes, but rather for "cleaning" or fusing the data. I imagine cases, where e.g. 3 points fall within the volume of one voxel. Then I would aim at either just setting this voxel to "activated" and discarding the 3 original points or alternatively I would like to calculate the euclidian mean of the points and return the thus "cleaned" point cloud as an irregularly structured one again.

I hope I could make my intentions clear enough: It's not about visualization and not necessarily about using volumetric cubes instead of points. It's only about manipulating possibily irregular point clouds in a structured way.

I was thinking about kd-tree or octree based solutions in this context, but can anybody point me in the proper direction? Hinting at existing MATLAB implementations would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is irregularly spaced, what you want to use is something which both smooths and interpolates your data points. A very good method for doing so is Gaussian process regression. [Here's an example for the same problem but in 2D](http://xcorr.net/2012/02/04/smoothing-a-non-uniformly-sampled-surface/).

Comment: Actually, I am not really interested in interpolation, but in "voxelizing" an irregular point cloud to a regular grid.

Comment: Smoothing, interpolating, binning, voxelizing... they're all the same basic thing. With a Gaussian process you would fit a smooth surface to your data point, then evaluate the smooth surface on a regularly-spaced 3d grid to obtain your voxelization. Easy as pie.

Comment: I understand that. However, there's several reasons this is not fully the solution I was looking for: 1) I didn't want to manipulate the original points in the first place. I know that I could weight them such that they are not adjusted in the interpolation, but then I can waive the interpolation procedure anyway. 2) I didn't want to create any new points but only voxelize the original ones. 3) I have worked with Gauss-Markov processes of 1st and 2nd order - but only in 1D. And I have not yet figured how to extend them to the 3D case.